# I'm trying to create a code that finds the topological order for the network. When I run the program it usually stops and keeps running forever

Tags: python, network-programming

from link import Link
from node import Node
from path import Path
from od import OD

import sys
import traceback
import utils

class BadNetworkOperationException(Exception):
"""
You can raise this exception if you try a network action which is invalid
(e.g., trying to find a topological order on a network with cycles.)
"""
pass

class Network:
"""
This is the class used for transportation networks.  It uses the following
dictionaries to store the network; the keys are IDs for the network elements,
and the values are objects of the relevant type:
node -- network nodes; see node.py for description of this class
link -- network links; see link.py for description of this class
ODpair -- origin-destination pairs; see od.py
path -- network paths; see path.py.  Paths are NOT automatically generated
when the network is initialized (you probably wouldn't want this,
the number of paths is exponential in network size.)

```
    The network topology is expressed both in links (through the tail and head
    nodes) and in nodes (forwardStar and reverseStar are Node attributes storing
    the IDs of entering and leaving links in a list).
          
    numNodes, numLinks, numZones -- self-explanatory
    firstThroughNode -- in the TNTP data format, transiting through nodes with
                      low IDs can be prohibited (typically for centroids; you
                      may not want vehicles to use these as "shortcuts").
                      When implementing shortest path or other routefinding,
                      you should prevent trips from using nodes with lower
                      IDs than firstThroughNode, unless it is the destination.
```

"""

def **init**(self, networkFile="", demandFile=""):
"""
Class initializer; if both a network file and demand file are specified,
will read these files to fill the network data structure.
"""
self.numNodes = 0
self.numLinks = 0
self.numZones = 0
self.firstThroughNode = 0

```
   self.node = dict()
   self.link = dict()
   self.ODpair = dict()
   self.path = dict()

   if len(networkFile) > 0 and len(demandFile) > 0:
       self.readFromFiles(networkFile, demandFile)
```

def findLeastEnteringLinks(self):
"""
This method should return the ID of the node with the *least* number
of links entering the node.  Ties can be broken arbitrarily.
"""
#  *** YOUR CODE HERE ***
# Replace the following statement with your code.
# raise utils.NotYetAttemptedException
minvalue = 1000
for i in self.node:
if (minvalue > len(self.node[i].reverseStar)):
minvalue = len(self.node[i].reverseStar)
idnode= i
return idnode

def formAdjacencyMatrix(self):
"""
This method should produce an adjacency matrix, with rows and columns
corresponding to each node, and entries of 1 if there is a link connecting
the row node to the column node, and 0 otherwise.  This matrix should
be stored in self.adjacencyMatrix, which is a dictionary of dictionaries:
the first key is the "row" (tail) node, and the second key is the "column"
(head) node.
"""
self.adjacencyMatrix = dict()
for i in self.node:
self.adjacencyMatrix[i] = dict()

```
    #  *** YOUR CODE HERE ***
    # Replace the following statement with your code. 
    # raise utils.NotYetAttemptedException
    for i in self.node:
         for j in self.node:
             self.adjacencyMatrix[i][j]=0
    for ij in self.link:
         self.adjacencyMatrix[self.link[ij].tail][self.link[ij].head]=1
    return self.adjacencyMatrix
```

def findTopologicalOrder(self):
"""
This method should find a topological order for the network, storing
the order in the 'order' attribute of the nodes, i.e.:
self.node[5].order
should store the topological label for node 5.

```
   The topological order is generally not unique, this method can return any
   valid order.  The nodes should be labeled 1, 2, 3, ... up through numNodes.
  
   If the network has cycles, a topological order does not exist.  The presence
   of cycles can be detected in the algorithm for finding a topological order,
   and you should raise an exception if this is detected.
   """
   #  *** YOUR CODE HERE ***
   # Replace the following statement with your code. 
   # raise utils.NotYetAttemptedException
   for i in self.node:
       self.node[i].order = []
   node_list= list()
   for i in self.node:
       if len(self.node[i].reverseStar) == 0:
           node_list.append(i)
           break
   if len(node_list)== 0:
       raise BadNetworkOperationException()
   while (len(node_list)!=self.numNodes):
       for i in [x for x in self.node if x not in node_list]:
           incoming_nodes = [int(j[1]) for j in self.node[i].reverseStar if j not in node_list]
           if (len(incoming_nodes)== 0):
               node_list.append(i)
               break
   for k in range(len(node_list)):
       self.node[node_list[k]].order = k+1
   return self.node[i].order
```

Comment: 1. You need to properly format your code by starting the blocks with ```py and ending it with ```. 2. You need to give more explanation for the code and how it's going wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to complete and assignment for a transportation network class. here is the link with all the files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/19iYoPrKKU_4MXenPpC1bBI8dmrzsxaWa/view?usp=sharing 
Inside the folder, there is a word file explaining all 4 problems. I've already completed the first 2 problems. There is a file called grader, when you run that files it gives you the score for all 4 problems. Currently, I'm stuck with problem 3 and have no idea how to do problem 4.  I have no background in coding and was given this random homework which has a lot of weight.